# If $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of $G$ and $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime. Is $KH$ a subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My teacher leaves us a question on class:

> If $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of $G$ and $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime. Is $KH$ a subgroup of $G$?

I am not quite sure about it...My thought is that $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then $KH$ is something like a direct sum? I'm not quite sure if my attempt is right...

Also I know that $HK\leq G$ iff $HK=KH$, but I think this won't help me out...

Can somebody give me some hints? Or maybe some counterexaples? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well in $A_5$ there are subgroups $\langle (12)(34)\rangle$ and $\langle (125)\rangle$ of coprime order. I leave you to calculate the product set ...

Comment: @ancientmathematician Is this a counterexaple? How do you come up with it... I don't know any easy way to calculate the product set of Symmetric Groups or Alternating Group, is there any good way?

Comment: You just have to check whether $HK=KH$ or not. If not, one element is enough, which is in one set, but not in the other.

Comment: (a) my bad, the second group should be $\langle (135)\rangle$; (b) you only need to observe that the product $(12)(34)(135)=(12345)$ has order $5$ which would be a contradiction of Lagrange if $HK$ were a subgroup (its order would be $2\times 3=6$). (c) I just knew.

Comment: From the duplicate: In the symmetric group $S_4$, you can take $H = \langle (1,2,3)\rangle$ and $K=\langle (1,4)(2,3)\rangle$ (among many other choices).  Then it's easy to check that $HK \neq KH$, so $HK$ is not a subgroup of $S_4$.  (Or, just directly check that $(1,2,4), (1,2,3)\in HK$, but $(1,2,4)\cdot(1,2,3) = (1,3)(2,4)\not\in HK$.)